# Is there a workaround to use the host's network in Docker for Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

Since Docker for Mac does not use Virtualbox but rather uses xhyve there is no straightforward way to access my mac's network (specifically for VPN and network attached devices) using `network_mode: host` or `--network host`.

I've searched and searched but have found no simple workaround. The best solution I've figured out is to run a Linux virtualbox then install docker on that and execute `docker-compose up` or `docker run` in there. Not ideal at all.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/155 is an open issue since 2016-08 and not closed as of 2018-12

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem to be possible. There are some limitation in docker for mac. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

On the other hand, starting a VM and installing docker on it might not help. With network mode as **host**, the container will use directly the network interfaces for the VM and not those of the MAC host. So you will end up in a case similar to that of using docker directly on your mac machine.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the VM network to be the host's network?