# Possible to scan network from dockerized Tshark?

Tags: macos, docker, wireshark

This might be a pretty dumb question, if so, forgive me for that ;) I was wondering if it's actually possible to scan my own network, to which my laptop is connected to, from a dockerized container?
I am running Tshark from my docker container, but the only packages which are passing by are looking like this:

```
Capturing on 'eth0'
  1 0.000000000 fe80::cc97:7fff:fe93:48f -> ff02::2      ICMPv6 70 Router Solicitation from ce:97:7f:93:04:8f
  2 8.928523400 fe80::cc97:7fff:fe93:48f -> ff02::2      ICMPv6 70 Router Solicitation from ce:97:7f:93:04:8f
  3 25.565048800 fe80::cc97:7fff:fe93:48f -> ff02::2      ICMPv6 70 Router Solicitation from ce:97:7f:93:04:8f
  4 57.528334500 fe80::cc97:7fff:fe93:48f -> ff02::2      ICMPv6 70 Router Solicitation from ce:97:7f:93:04:8f
  5 122.088671000 fe80::cc97:7fff:fe93:48f -> ff02::2      ICMPv6 70 Router Solicitation from ce:97:7f:93:04:8f
```

I don't receive much more packages, even if I don't specify any interface it automatically tries capturing from eth0 which gives the above mentioned results. My laptop itself IS connected to the internet by the way.

And since I know I need to expose specific ports if I would like to access the web interface, running in a container on port 5000 for example, I was wondering if Tshark only works when I expose most of the ports...

Comment: What's the supposed benefit of using docker, here? The separation between containers, and containers and the host, is exactly what you *don't* want, apparently. Can you work around that with sufficient diligence? Maybe. Is it worth doing? Probably not.

Comment: The benefit should be easy shipment, installation and removal of my applications, actually. This Dockerfile is part of some other Dockerfiles where different applications are running on, which will process the pcap data. But only this container should be able to actually intercept traffic from a chosen network.

Comment: If this isn't possible, the only solution left is installing tshark on the laptop and send all data through an exposed port to the Docker containers

Comment: Doing that "right" would require the ability in Docker to expose network capture interfaces to be claimed by a container, or at least duplicating the traffic so the container can capture it. I don't think there's anything native in Docker to do that in a way that allows for easy add/remove of the containers. If you don't mind changing the host config, you could try setting up a bridge (there are various sites talking about doing this to give containers "real" addresses on a "real" network), but there's a nonzero chance of hosing your host network config that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this as an answer because I think this will be as close as I will get. It seems that someone wrote a solution to this problem: https://jerrygamblin.com/2016/05/28/a-docker-container-to-capture-all-traffic-from-host/

The only problem with the above solution is that the `--net=host` (host network-mode) doesn't seem to work very properly on OSX: [Is there a workaround to use the host's network in Docker for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286741/is-there-a-workaround-to-use-the-hosts-network-in-docker-for-mac). So the best solution might be to run pyshark in combination with tshark locally and push all captured traffic to a docker instance, where I will store it and process it.

Or perhaps just use a device which runs on debian or similar, which doesn't have any problems with the host network mode.